Install OpenJDK 22 on Ubuntu 24.04
I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04, on my Ubuntu 23.10 I had OpenJDK 22 ea from apt, now I can't see any 22 version, why is that? was it deleted from the repository?
I've seen this page: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/noble/arm64/openjdk-22-jre/22+36-1build1

Same issue - my openjdk 22 was uninstalled on upgrade, and I can only install v21 now, not v22.

Interim Ubuntu releases as 23.10 Mantic Minotaur may include or make as available unstable or non-LTS packages as jdk-22. That openjdk-22 for Noble Numbat for arm64 you link was present by the time Noble was in development stage, but later rebuilt(due to xz utils security issue) and finally deleted. So security concerns and mainly not being an LTS release were the reasons to exclude it from being in 24.04.
LTS releases as 24.04 Noble Numbat tend to include just stable, LTS, secure packages. That is why, if you search for 'openjdk' in Noble, you just find openjdk-8/11/17/21, which are all LTS releases. Currently, apt only offers openjdk-22 for Mantic and Oracular(future interim release), but it is not officially available for Noble: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-22
Anyways, if previous mentioned and available LTS releases don't serve and you only want jdk-22 you can always get it and use it from a third-party as the other comments told you: Oracle's, Openjdk's builds, Azul's...It's up to you.

Maybe because it has such a short shelf-life: ends in September.
https://download.oracle.com/java/22/latest/jdk-22_linux-x64_bin.deb


I don't think this is the reason, that does't make any sense, ignoring all versions of Java till the next LTS release of Ubuntu, why deny users of this version?
I want OpenJDKs JRE, not Oracles


Not packaging is not the same as denying. Maybe it'll be included in the point release - who knows. If you're desperate just download https://jdk.java.net/22/ , unzip and set JAVA_HOME env var to that dir. Or try Azul, they have debs: get https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-22&os=linux&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk#zulu

you're correct.. but the advantage of installing from apt, is that if there are new (minor) version, it will updated automatically

Azul has an APT repository https://docs.azul.com/core/install/debian#install-from-azul-apt-repository
